# How to apply css to a class inside div?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, css, lightning-design-system

I want to specify styling to a class inside the overlay class. I want to specify padding style to slds-panel__section class. How to do that?
Below is the HTML and CSS but this is getting applied only to the overlay and if I want to apply padding inside panel__section it is not allowing me to do. Any help is appreciated!!

```
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="slds-panel slds-grid slds-grid_vertical slds-nowrap">
            <div class="slds-form slds-form_stacked slds-grow slds-scrollable_y">
                <div class="slds-panel__section ">
                    <c:ContactSelection />
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
   </div>

.THIS.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px; 
    max-width: 205px; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add a whitespace between your classes. `.foo.bar` would only apply to elements with both classes.: `class="foo bar"`.

What you need is an `.overlay` that is IN a `.THIS`(namespace) and a `.panel__section`, that is IN a `.THIS`.

So in your case this should work:

```
.THIS .overlay, .THIS .panel__section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px; 
    max-width: 205px; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

or if you only need the padding:

```
.THIS .panel__section {
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

I created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wsf32dz/5/) to play around